# Downgrade RCP app with P2

Tags: java, p2

Is it possible to downgrade an RCP app via P2?

#### What I want to achieve:

I have a P2 composite repository which contains several P2 repositories with different versions of my app. The composite repository has the following structure:

- 1.0.0

  - binary
  - plugins
  - artifacts.jar
  - content.jar
- 1.0.1

  - some content as above
- 1.0.2

  - some content as above
- compositeArtifacts.xml
- compositeContent.xml

In my application the user should have the possibility to select one of the versions (1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2) and then the app restarts in the selected version.

I have figured out how this works for an update via the [UpdateOperation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_api_overview.htm). But when I want to perform a downgrade I get the status `UpdateOperation.STATUS_NOTHING_TO_UPDATE`. Which is normal because I am already using the newest version.

As there is no DowngradeOperation, I wonder if it is possible to downgrade an application with P2.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible.

A clean way "simulate" a downgrade would be to perform an `UninstallOperation` and after an `InstallOperation`